SPFX workbench crashes when I try to enter "Preview" mode
This issue has only recently started happening (as in within the last week).
I can easily open the workbench, and I can even see the application in Edit mode. However, when I enter Preview mode, the entire page just becomes white indicating a crash. The console log displays the following errors:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: The value for "domElement" must not be null
at e.isNotNullOrUndefined (sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_7dafe6a6be2322500fc7b167b336d010.js:20:182688)
at e._renderError (sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_7dafe6a6be2322500fc7b167b336d010.js:243:54132)
at e.renderError (sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_7dafe6a6be2322500fc7b167b336d010.js:243:53204)
at sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_7dafe6a6be2322500fc7b167b336d010.js:243:63884

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'web')
at toabsoluteurl.js:27:46
at step (tslib.es6.js:102:1)
at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:83:45)
at tslib.es6.js:76:1
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at __awaiter (tslib.es6.js:72:1)
at toAbsoluteUrl (toabsoluteurl.js:12:21)
at operations.js:24:59
at step (tslib.es6.js:102:1)
at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:83:45)

Mind you, there has been NO code changes in the last week, and last time I was debugging in the workbench with this exact same code, there was no issues like this. I have tried in 3 different SPFX applications, and they all have the same issues.

Are you using PnP JS library in your SPFx code? Are you manipulating domElement from your code?

@GaneshSanap-MVP The only pnp library im using is the basic one for SFPX (pnp/sp). I'm not manipulating domElement either. The only reference is in the root webpart component.ts (ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement), and the same for onDispose where I unmount the domElement

Referring to Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'web') - check if you are initializing PnP JS library correctly as per the library version and passing context of web part correctly while initializing. I think error is related to this only. Check: PnP JS - Getting Started.

I've tried using the guide and it did not work. This has not been an issue for almost 2 years and has only just now started happening within the last week.

I have same issue even with vanilla 1.19.0 helloworld

A workaround I've found is - instead of using workbench, I append the following tag after the SharePoint site in the URL:
?loadSPFX=true&debugManifestsFile=https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js
So the URL would be:
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site?loadSPFX=true&debugManifestsFile=https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js

You can also change the serve.json file to use the new URL instead of the workbench as well.
This just further confirms there something wrong in the communication between the SharePoint workbench and PnP currently.

Yes, I've got the exact same issue here. Everything is fine in Edit mode but fails to load as soon as you hit the Preview.  Like other, this just started happening for no apparent reason.  I have the same issue on multiple target environments and with different development machines. It is clear something Microsoft has done at the back end.
Thanks for the work around, which is the same mode that we need to use when developing Application Customizers and Command Extensions etc.

Hi Colin - you're welcome!

Use URL in this format while checking SPFx solution:
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/SitePages/PageName.aspx?loadSPFX=true&debugManifestsFile=https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js#


Hello Christian, did you find a solution for this problem? I am facing the same issue out of a sudden. If I replace the initialPage with the one you suggested above, the home page of my SharePoint site opens but then how can I add the WebPart to try it out? Thanks

Hi @Bill - I believe if you just deploy the webpart and add the deployed webpart to the actual site, you should be able to use the method above. The hosted site just uses the base site and the localhost manifest to determine changes. It acts as a workbench, but instead of isolating the code to a workbench, it is using the actual site to perform changes. Hope it makes sense
